bash: !IP-adress/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/102/httpPreview
Я работаю с камерой HIKVISION и Orange PI PC Plus с ОС Ubuntu для оранджа. Когда я запускаю команду в терминале для открытия ссылки в браузере: xdg-open http://:@:/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/102/httpPreview
мне выдает ошибку. И да, айпи компьютера был поменян на 192.168.1.2, айпи камеры 192.168.1.64.
Ссылка на официальную инструкцию с http-командами: https://www.hikvision.com/content/dam/hikvision/en/support/download/how-to/ipc/How%20to%20Get%20IPC%20MJPEG%20Stream%20via%20HTTP%20Commands.pdf

вы предлагаете нам угадать какую выдаёт ошибку ваша команда ?

ой да,извините ошибка: event not found
